# Reverting events changed with patch

Tags: google-calendar-api

I changes a users calendar with the patch command and removed notes they had written.
Is there a way to revert the calendar back to before the change?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not store event history if you over wrote it and did not store it internally within your own system there is no way to get back the data

Comment: Thank you, I did have that functionality but it did not work.

Comment: testing with a test account next time might be a good idea 

Comment: I had the line commented out to keep existing data... so I was aware the situation could happen... and it worked perfectly as it was intended to do.. and had done thousands of times before... but thanks for the advice